# Convert YouTube M4a DASH to regular M4a with Hex Editor

Tags: binary, hex, hex-editors

Using various browser extensions allows download of YouTube content as audio M4a format.

However, according to this post

https://superuser.com/questions/837067/convert-youtube-dash-audio-youtube-dl-to-m4a-aac-dl/837076#837076

the M4a codec is DASH, which is not widely recognized / built-in (yet) to players such as VLC.

Reading into the meaning of `container`, the above post seems to suggest that if one could change bytes 8 to 11 from DASH to MP4 then the file would immediately be playable..?

I tried this with a hex editor, but the file was not rendered playable in VLC.

Am I missing something basic (for example, deleting byte 11 - I made it 00?), or is there a lot more to it?

PS - I was able to convert the file using Foobar2000 1.37beta and the MP3 convert ability, but a hex editor would be faster for my purposes.

Comment: Browser extension used for DL was TubeEnhancer in FFox

Comment: I don't see anything about modifying a few bytes in that link.

Comment: That is why I wrote "reading into the meaning of container" -- if this is just a container setting, then perhaps changing that value will do the trick. This is what I am asking.

Comment: Sorry, "the above post seems to suggest that if one could change bytes 8 to 11" seemed to indicate you read that in the other question. Do you have a link to where you read this?

Comment: Maybe try 20 (space) instead of 00 (null) for the 4th byte. See also http://www.ftyps.com/

Comment: @FooBar Good idea, but no joy. That's a GREAT resource, though. Thanks.